# ado.net entity framework delete rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I may be completely blind and stupid, but I cannot find any method generated by ADO.NET Entity Data Model that would somehow delete rows from my table. I didn't want to create a custom query. So how do I do that? Please help.

I don't have the method DeleteOnSubmit... don't know why. This is the code I wanted to use.

```
var deleteOrderDetails =
from details in db.OrderDetails
where details.OrderID == 11000
select details;

foreach (var detail in deleteOrderDetails)
{
db.OrderDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(detail);
}

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of alterations needed:

```
db.DeleteObject(detail);
```

and

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

Kindness,

Dan

PS: Have you been using Linq to SQL and then swapped to the Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes. That would be the case. Also - can I delete multiple rows at once by this?

Comment: You can do mutiple delete objects per SaveChanges, yes :)

Comment: No, what I meant was if I could do dv.DeleteObject(deleteOrderDetails);??

Comment: make a list of objects you can remove and then iterate appyling the  Contetxt.Model.Remove(item); when finish your iteration simply apply Context.SaveChanges and should works

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738270/ef-4-0-many-to-many-relationship-problem-with-deletes/2738389#2738389))

I assume you have the `Orders` table, and `OrderDetails` is related to it via `OrderID`.

```
var order = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o=> o.OrderID == 11000);
if(order != null)
{
  order.OrderDetails.Clear();
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This should delete all the order details associated with that order.

edit: fixed the code